# How to add my subscription data to update my previous query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, react-apollo

I have one query and one subscription, what I am trying to do is add my data to previous query so that it shows the full list.

I have one `query` which is returning me list of students and I am rendering that on UI like below

```
    function Test(props) {
    const { loading, data: dta } = useQuery(GETSTUDENTS);
    const { data: d } = useSubscription(GETSUBSTUDENTS, {
        onSubscriptionData: ({ subscriptionData: { data } }) => {
            let fname = data.getSubStudent.fname;
            let lname = data.getSubStudent.lname;
            dta.getStudents.push({ fname, lname });
        },
    });

    return (
        <div className="">
            {dta &&
                dta.getStudents.map((li) => {
                    <div>
                        <p>{li.fname}</p>
                        <p>{li.lname}</p>
                    </div>;
                })}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Test;
```

But the main issue is the above one is not updating the cache so when I change the routes and come bqack again it takes the previous data only.

So What I wnat to know na what is the best way to do this, I have check `subscribeToMore` also but did not get idea How to implement that and how it works with hooks.

I am getting some data from subscription and on that basis I want to change some other part so can I use `refetchQueries` I did not found any good tutorial which uses hooks (react-apollo-hooks) using qraphql

Answer (score 0):

First, you can just use the pooling option of the useQuery instead of subscription,
I suggest you check it.
From Apollo docs:

> "In the majority of cases, your client should not use subscriptions to
> stay up to date with your backend. Instead, you should poll
> intermittently with queries, or re-execute queries on demand when a
> user performs a relevant action."
> [Apollo subscription](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/)

If you still want to use the subscription I think you should use the subscribeToMore and to update your cache policy inside the apollo cache file:

```
 const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Agenda: {
      fields: {
        tasks: {
          merge(existing = [], incoming: any[]) {
            return [...existing, ...incoming];
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

You can read more about it here: [merge cahce](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-field-behavior/)

And check that video: [youtube apollo cache](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_j8QckQN5I&t=1751s)

Comment: the links you ahve shared I have seen them, but I did not get what are you  doing in that `new InMemoryCache`, could you explain a bit using my above code, how should I proceed

Comment: You should have a file with the InMemoryCache conf,
and then you need to initialize your apollo client with your cache:
  const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    link: ...,
    cache: apolloCache,
    connectToDevTools: ...,
...
  })
in-memory cache, you can define how you want to merge your calls, lets  For example Users query:
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        users: {
          keyArgs: false,
          merge(existing: User[], incoming: User[]) {
            return [...(existing || []), ...incoming]
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },